# How to link two constructors and inherit them as prototype to an Object?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, prototype-chain

I am working with `prototypes` in JavaScript (I am new to JS) and stuck with the following snippet of JS code:

I have created two functions:

**Function 1**

```
function sample1() {
    this.uname = "Andrew";
}
```

**Function 2**

```
function sample2() {
    this.age = 21;
}
```

I inherited the properties of `sample2` to `sample1` as follows:

```
sample1.prototype = sample2;
```

Upto this, everything works fine, like I could see `sample1` having `sample2` as its prototype. But, the problem is with the creation of an Object using `sample1` which contains the property of `sample2`.

```
let test = new sample1;
```

Now, trying to access the property of `sample1` gives the correct output.

```
test.uname;
```

But, trying to access `age` gives output as `undefined`.

**Question:**

How to access the `age` property using `test` Object?

**Note: The above is tried using Chrome Developer Tools - Console**

Thanks.

Comment: You need to call `sample2` as its a function. Inheriting from it makes no sense. `sample1.prototype = new sample2` would work

Comment: just a convention, but saves a whole lot of confusion.  Uppercase the first character of the functions if these are to be used like classes..  eg..   `Sample1` instead of `sample1`..

Comment: @JonasW. not quite - you need for sample2's prototype chain to be associated with sample1's prototype chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uname` and `age` properties are created by the constructors directly on each instance that they initialise. There is no point in using prototypical inheritance here. Just run both constructors:

```
function sample2() {
    this.age = 21;
}
function sample1() {
    sample2.call(this); // runs the other constructor on this instance
    this.uname = "Andrew";
}
```

This works quite like a `super` call when overriding methods.

> I am working with prototypes in JavaScript

Not yet :-) Your prototype objects are empty.

> I inherited the properties of sample2 to sample1 as follows:
>
> ```
> sample1.prototype = sample2;
> ```

Uh, you shouldn't do that. `sample2` is a function object, that's nothing you'd usually want anything to inherit from. Notice that `sample1.prototype` is what all instances created using `new sample1` will inherit from - they're not functions. You probably are looking for

```
sample1.prototype = Object.create(sample2.prototype);
```

Comment: NB: you will need the `Object.create()` if you want to use methods that are attached to the base class's prototype, and not just simple per-instance properties directly attached to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to build a prototype chain in ES5.

Start with your base class:

```
// base class definition
function Sample1(name) {
    this.uname = name;
}

// with an example function stored on the prototype
Sample1.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.uname;
}
```

and then sub-class it, with the appropriate prototype chaining:

```
// create the sub-class constructor
function Sample2(name, age) {
    // invokes superclass constructor, passing any params it needs
    Sample1.call(this, name);

    // define subclass per-instance properties
    this.age = age;
}

//
// *** THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT ****
//
// create a correctly chained prototype for Sample2
Sample2.prototype = Object.create(Sample1.prototype);

// and then re-associate the correct constructor method
// to assist with debugging, console.log, etc
Sample2.prototype.constructor = Sample2;

// and add methods to it
Sample2.prototype.getAge = function() {
    return this.age;
}
```

You can then use your new inherited "classes"

```
// pass multiple parameters, and then query the object
var test = new Sample2("Andrew", 21);
console.log(test.getName());
console.log(test.getAge());

// this should show "Sample2"
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(test));

// these should both be "true"
console.log(test instanceof Sample2);
console.log(test instanceof Sample1);
```